# Error: my website Form submission fails to send

Tags: javascript, php, html, backend, web-frontend

first of all my level is 0 in PHP and i'm learning to make websites.

my PHP Form doesn't work, when i press send message button this error pops out "Error: Form submission failed and no error message returned from: contact.php". I don't know what the problem is.

This is html form :

```
<form id="contact-form" action="contact.php" method="post" data-toggle="validator" role="form" class="php-email-form">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group mt-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group mt-3">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="my-3">
                <div class="loading">Loading</div>
                <div class="error-message"></div>
                <div class="sent-message">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
              </div>
              
              <div class="text-center">
                <button id="submit" type="submit">Send Message</button>
              </div>
            </form>
```

This is contact.php

```
<?php
  $receiving_email_address = 'myemail@blabla.com';

  $to = 'myemail@blabla.com';
  $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
  $from = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
  $subject = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'subject', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
  $message = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'message', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

  if (filter_var($from, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $headers = ['From' => ($name?"<$name> ":'').$from,
            'X-Mailer' => 'PHP/' . phpversion()
           ];

    mail($to, $subject, $message."\r\n\r\nfrom: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $headers);
    die('OK');
    
} else {
    die('Invalid address');
}

  echo $contact->send();
?>
```

this is my contact.js

```
(function () {
  "use strict";

  let forms = document.querySelectorAll('.php-email-form');

  forms.forEach( function(e) {
    e.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      let thisForm = this;

      let action = thisForm.getAttribute('action');
      let recaptcha = thisForm.getAttribute('data-recaptcha-site-key');
      
      if( ! action ) {
        displayError(thisForm, 'The form action property is not set!')
        return;
      }
      thisForm.querySelector('.loading').classList.add('d-block');
      thisForm.querySelector('.error-message').classList.remove('d-block');
      thisForm.querySelector('.sent-message').classList.remove('d-block');

      let formData = new FormData( thisForm );

      if ( recaptcha ) {
        if(typeof grecaptcha !== "undefined" ) {
          grecaptcha.ready(function() {
            try {
              grecaptcha.execute(recaptcha, {action: 'php_email_form_submit'})
              .then(token => {
                formData.set('recaptcha-response', token);
                php_email_form_submit(thisForm, action, formData);
              })
            } catch(error) {
              displayError(thisForm, error)
            }
          });
        } else {
          displayError(thisForm, 'The reCaptcha javascript API url is not loaded!')
        }
      } else {
        php_email_form_submit(thisForm, action, formData);
      }
    });
  });

  function php_email_form_submit(thisForm, action, formData) {
    fetch(action, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
      headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
    })
    .then(response => {
      return response.text();
    })
    .then(data => {
      thisForm.querySelector('.loading').classList.remove('d-block');
      if (data.trim() == 'OK') {
        thisForm.querySelector('.sent-message').classList.add('d-block');
        thisForm.reset(); 
      } else {
        throw new Error(data ? data : 'Form submission failed and no error message returned from: ' + action); 
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      displayError(thisForm, error);
    });
  }

  function displayError(thisForm, error) {
    thisForm.querySelector('.loading').classList.remove('d-block');
    thisForm.querySelector('.error-message').innerHTML = error;
    thisForm.querySelector('.error-message').classList.add('d-block');
  }

})();
```

Comment: If php error reporting is switched off you might get a blank response in the case it crashes. Hopefully in that scenario it'll log the error to a file instead. If not, enable php error reporting (it's easy to Google how).

Comment: Anyway, as far as I can see `echo $contact->send();` might cause a problem because I don't see `$contact` defined anywhere in the php. What are you expecting that line to do?

Comment: i 've this php contact code with a template website i'm trying to do!

Comment: Ok. And? I'm not sure how that's relevant. It certainly doesn't constitute a response to anything in my earlier comments.

Comment: i mean , maybe there's missing a function or php code that's missing relating to that $contact line that was missing on that template (like ive said : got it as is)

Comment: Maybe...how should we know? We know nothing about this template or what it's supposed to do. If you bought / downloaded it from somewhere and it doesn't work properly, contact the maintainer for support in the first instance.

Comment: i thought posting the relevant code could be enough for someone to figure what's missing/wrong since i'm no expert,thanks and sorry for your time on it ,cheers.

Comment: We know something's probably missing or incorrect, that's clear enough, but we can't tell you how to fix it because we don't really know the full purpose of this code, we don't know what other code exists in the same project/template, and we don't know the original author's intention for how it should operate. Most questions here involve code that the person asking the question has been trying to write themselves, or at least has a basic understanding of, and they can therefore clarify these kinds of points to enable us to understand the purpose.

Comment: About the only suggestion I can make really is to remove `echo $contact->send();` entirely and see if that helps. Or if you can find the original source code of the template online (e.g. on github or somewhere like that), you can check whether it contains differences or additional code compared to what you've got in your project.

Comment: the purpose of this code is as far as i understand is : submit html website contact us form (name,email,subject,message) by email in the background (maybe ajax) without reloading page and displaying (Your message has been sent. Thank you) under the form if the form was sent correctly

Comment: Yes but I mean what the purpose of the `$contact->send();` command specifically is supposed to be, and whether it's important - that's what we cannot easily know. I can see there is already a separate `mail()` command whose purpose is clearly to send the email.